# Why does didLoad not fire?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a startup view controller which has the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self loadMainMenu:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This does the following:

```
-(IBAction) loadMainMenu:(id) sender {
      [self.view insertSubview:mainMenuViewController.view atIndex:0];
}
```

My mainMenu.h has the following:

```
-(IBAction) loadRules:(id) sender;
-(IBAction) loadPlayGame:(id) sender; 
-(IBAction) loadHighScores:(id) sender;
-(IBAction) loadAbout:(id) sender;
```

mainMenu.m has the below and has a button tied to this in order to show the view:

```
-(IBAction) loadPlayGame:(id) sender {
playGame *playGameViewController = [[rules alloc]
                                initWithNibName:@"playGame"
                                bundle:nil];

    [self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentModalViewController:playGameViewController animated:YES];
    [playGameViewController release];
}
```

Now the View for playGame does come up but the viewDidLoad never gets hit.

What am I doing wrong?  Is this not the way to load the view?  As always, thanks in advance for any and all help.

BTW:  The code:  [self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve]; does nothing...any and all view show up as a croll up from bottom.

Geo...

Comment: Does your view controller appear properly, aside from the missing viewDidLoad? Do other methods (viewWillAppear:, viewDidAppear:) fire? You need to se the modalTransitionStyle on your new viewcontroller, not the current one (the one that will be presented).

Comment: Don't think this will fix it but you probably want to call `super viewDidLoad` first.

Answer (score 1):

This code makes no sense:

```
playGame *playGameViewController = [[rules alloc]
                            initWithNibName:@"playGame"
                            bundle:nil];
```

What is `rules` here? Is it a instance variable? It should the the class name of a view controller. Like for example `PlayGameViewController`.

Either you are doing that wrong or your naming conventions for classes and nibs are *very* wrong.